# Tab Bar not showing up in the simulator

Tags: xcode, mapkit, tabbar

In interface builder my tab bar shows up, but it won't show up in my simulator. Ive tried repositioning it and messing around with the stuff in interface builder but its still not showing up. Why is this? 
Here is the coding

#import 
 #import

@interface mapview : UIViewController  {

```
 MKMapView *mapView; 


}


-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)pushBack;

-(IBAction)findmyass:(id)sender;








@end

#import "mapview.h"
#import "NewClass.h"


@implementation mapview




-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];  
mapView.delegate=self;  

[self.view addSubview:mapView];  
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(displayMap) toTarget:self withObject:nil];  



[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];

MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
region.center.latitude = 39.956907;
region.center.longitude = -75.610229;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];


NewClass *ann = [[NewClass alloc] init];
ann.title = @"Vigil Location of Chester County ";
ann.subtitle = @"8 S. Wayne St. West Chester, PA 19382";
ann.coordinate = region.center;
[mapView addAnnotation:ann];

-(void)displayMap {  
MKCoordinateRegion region;  
MKCoordinateSpan span;  
span.latitudeDelta=0.2;  
span.longitudeDelta=0.2;  

CLLocationCoordinate2D location;  
location.latitude = -35;  
location.longitude = 146.2381;  
region.span=span;  
region.center=location;  

[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];  
[mapView regionThatFits:region];  
}  

- (void)dealloc {  
[mapView release];  
[super dealloc];  
}  




/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a        
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
 }

 - (void)viewDidUnload {
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
 }






-(IBAction)pushBack {

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }

 -(IBAction)findmyass:(id)sender {

mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

 } 

 @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if your mapView is covering over the tab bar since you are initializing the mapView with the same frame as your entire view (self.view.bounds).

If that's the issue, try

```
CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
frame.size.height = frame.size.height - 40;
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

instead of

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

That should tell you if that was your problem. If so, you should probably get a reference to the tab bar and subtract its height, rather than the hard coded "40".

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you. Finding the users location isn't working now though? Any tips on this?

Comment: Glad that worked. Please click the 'check' to accept the answer.